# AWS WSS API Gateway time out on apigwManagementApi.postToConnection, Lambda + VPC

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc

I have implemented websockets using aws lambda and api gateway, it seemed to work fine until I moved it behind a VPC, right now I am able to connect to the WSS and it is able to communicate with dynamodb and elastic search service (through vpc endpoint) but when I try to send data to a connection:

> await apigwManagementApi.postToConnection(params).promise()

I get timeout (lambda function times out). I have NAT and IGW configured to a public subnet.

any suggestions, please?

thanks
Sajid

Comment: did you get a solution for this.. I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: Yes, I had my lambda inside a VPC and that VPC had only private security groups. i moved created once public security group and added an internet gateway to and it started working fine for me. hope this helps you :)